# Trigger / disparador para oracle

Tags: php, oracle, trigger

Necesito hacer un triger/disparador para que cuando alguien inserte un valor se modifique y se inserte otro.

Es decir,yo desde una pagina web voy a insertar un listado de productos con su ID,pero la base de datos al ser en oracle no tiene auto_increment.

Por lo que desde la web siempre voy a pasar el mismo ID pero luego en la base de datos con un disparador quiero que se modifique el valor del id y se cambie por el ultimo id + 1.

No se si es posible hacer esto,si alguien puede echarme una mano lo agradecería,nunca he trabajo con trigeers

Comment: Podrías utilizar la combinación de trigger y secuencias. Por aquí un ejemplo, seguro te servirá: https://echaleunvistazo.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/campo-autoincremental-en-oracle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Ey que tal amigo!

Lo ideal seria que en la base de datos hagas uso de secuencias, acá te dejo documentación al respecto.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/oracleya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=193&punto=1&inicio=

Y acá te dejo documentación de triggers, con un ejemplo trayendo el valor actual de una secuencia y al realizar la inserción el campo id tendria el valor siguiente de la secuencia, por lo tanto seria como un autoincremental.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/54/Triggers-en-PLSQL.aspx

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER nombre_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON nombre_tabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     SELECT nombre_secuencia.nextval INTO :NEW.id
     FROM DUAL;
END
```

Asi cuando hagas el insert desde el backend no le pases ningún valor al id, es decir, en vez de hacer esto:

```
INSERT INTO nombre_tabla(id,campo1) VALUES(1,'valor_campo1')
```

haces esto:

```
INSERT INTO nombre_tabla(campo1) VALUES('valor_campo1')
```

Y ya el trigger actualiza solo el campo id, como si fuera autoincremental.

¡Espero te sirva, saludos!